# rsync ssh fails to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, opensuse

When trying to connect via rsync to download a file using the following command:

```
rsync -Pav http://some.domainname.com/file.tar.gz
```

The following error is given to me

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

If i try and download the same file using the ftp commands instead it works fine. If i try and use the rsync command from a pc on another network instead this also works fine, so it seems to be something environmental.

The customers client pc sits behind a proxy server, but all the proxy address details have been added to the system, and i'm able to browse, ftp, and ssh onto a test server without any issues. Is there anything that may be blocking rsync from running?

Comment: This rsync doesn't seem to like your http part (or is it configured to use ssh access by default). You could try and replace the http with rsync protocol and use ftp access, e.g. `rsync -av rsync://ftp.ensembl.org/ensembl/pub/current_embl/homo_sapiens .`

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing `curl/wget` and `rsync`.

```bash
wget http://some.domainname.com/file.tar.gz
```

or

```
rsync a_user@some.domainename.com:/path/to/webdir/file.tar.gz /local/dest/dir
```